# Calling a Matlab script from Java without license

Tags: java, matlab

I've implemented a Java-App which collects data. The app should call a Matlab script which does it's calculation with the collected data and delivers a result. How to do this?

And is there a way, that the user can use the Java-App from his own computer without a Matlab license?

I've got absolutely no idea about Matlab. It's only my task to call the script from my Java-App with the generated data as input.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: To be honest: Nothing, I justed started with the research and I don't even have a Matlab license so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Matlab Runtime](https://de.mathworks.com/products/compiler/mcr.html) to run compiled Matlab code on mashines that has no Matlab installation. Here is a [Getting Started](https://de.mathworks.com/videos/getting-started-standalone-applications-using-matlab-compiler-100088.html). The generation of the compiled code still needs a valid Matlab license.

Another alternative that requires no license is [Octave](http://octave-online.net/) which can be also [used from Java](http://xmodulo.com/how-to-call-octave-from-java.html) however the syntax is a bit different.

Finally you can take a look on [MatConsoleCtl](https://github.com/diffplug/matconsolectl) -which was forked from the good old [matlabcontrol](https://code.google.com/archive/p/matlabcontrol/)- provides a really convenient usage to execute commands in a Matlab instance from Java. This approach starts a Matlab instance that requires a license again.

Comment: Your opening statement is not true. The [MATLAB Runtime](https://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/mcr.html) can be used to run compiled MATLAB code (which needs a MATLAB license to generate) on a machine without a license.

Comment: ah yes, you are right - I totally forgot about ML Runtime. I update the first part of the answer. Thank you!:)

Comment: Thanks! The Matlab Runtime sounds like a reasonable solution for me.